# docker registry v2, where do buffered or pushed images get stored

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have setup a [local docker registry v2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) and images have been pushed and pulled frequently with various tags.

- Where do the pushed images get stored (pushed from the docker client) ? Do they get store within the registry container or on the host OS ?
- How to be purge the pushed/buffered images from the registry for free disk space ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default, your registry data is persisted as a docker volume on the
>   host filesystem.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#storage

If you don't mount the volume, you can locate where it is persisted using `docker inspect`

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#locating-a-volume